# Magento: Populate column data from another table

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

I'm using Magento Community 1.6.2.

Due to a bad import, my media positions are all screwed up.

To repair I would like to export catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value and edit the **position** field. Unfortunately catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value shows only value_id as an identifier to which product/image is associated.

catalog_product_entity_media_gallery (on the other hand) contains the field **value**, which is the image path. It also contains the field value_id.

To prep I added the **value** column to catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value

**Now to my problem:**

I would like to join the new **value** field I created in **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value** with the info from **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery** using the value_id to associate the right value with its corresponding **value_id**.

Help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean join the two tables together on value_id ?

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` v
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` g
ON g.value_id = v.value_id
```

Comment: Thanks. This mapped the information in the way that I was hoping for, but does not actually save the information in the value column.